# java - PostgreSQL Function not able to execute through java code

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a function created in PostgreSQL. I am trying to use this function in SQL query and trying to execute it in Java code. However, I am getting error as 'my_function(int, unknown) does not exist.

`select * from my_table where my_id = (select get_my_function(1223, TO_DATE('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:DD') as my_id))`

When I am trying to execute SQL query in DBeaver it is working fine. However, it is not working when I am trying to call it through Java code.
Any help related to this is appreciated.

Thanks,

Avinash

Comment: You don't show the code that invokes the function nor the error message, so you cannot get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one closing bracket, just before `as my_id`:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_id = (
        select get_my_function(
                1223,
                TO_DATE('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:DD')
            ) as my_id
    )
```

Try to copy query from DBeaver and not retype it. Query must work in jdbc too.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for your reply... This is the typo error in the post, however, actually, it is not able to recognize the declared function which is used in the query. As I mentioned, I am able to run it in DBeaver, but through JDBC it is not. Your expert solution will be appreciated.